# wxPython: What is the difference between a wx.Panel and a wx.Window?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I got the impression that Panel is better. Is that true?

What advantage does one have over the other? What reason is there to use one over the other?

Answer (score 20):

wx.Window is the base class for all widgets (not necessarily all **windows** - the name is misleading).

wx.Panel is a subclass of wx.Window, which is more tailored towards containing widgets inside it. For example, it by default allows moving between widgets using "tab", and handles a focus event in a way that is more useful with child widgets.

Comment: Is there any reason this answer was down-voted (once)? Is there anything wrong about it? If there is, it would be for the benefit of all to add a proper answer, or at least a comment explaining what's incorrect.

Comment: @Hexagon: Good shot at a first answer, +1.
@cool-RR: With that kind of attitude you shouldn't expect to get any answers. Not cool at all.

Comment: @mghie: I disagree. I asked a question and Hexagon gave an incomplete answer. I don't think down-voting should be considered offensive. I'm just saying I'm not satisfied with the answer he gave me, and I hope he or someone else will give a complete answer.

Comment: You can use your down-votes as you see fit obviously, but I think a down-vote should generally go to an answer that contains incorrect information (and hence may be misleading). But - your choice.